# How would I update each dataframe in orderedDict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dataframe, ordereddictionary

I have an excel file of three sheets:

```
Sheet1:
name   fav    date
blue    5     11/20/2020
orange  5     11/20/2020
red     5     11/20/2020
```

sheet 2 and 3 follows the same format (same column names as well)

I use pandas to read the excel file and it comes out as orderedDict:

```
dict = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name= None)
```

output:`

```
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',      name  fav       date
0  purple    3 2020-04-29
1     tan    2 2020-04-29
2    blue    1 2020-04-29), ('Sheet2',     name  fav       date
0  white    1 2020-04-29
1  black    2 2020-04-29
2   gray    3 2020-04-29), ('Sheet3',      name  fav       date
0    blue    5 2020-11-20
1  orange    5 2020-11-20
2     red    5 2020-11-20)])
```

If I wanted to do any manipulation to all three sheets with the same column names How would I do that?

like for instance If to add the letter 'g' at the end of each name column value in each sheet

ex:

```
Sheet1:
name     fav      date
blueg     5       11/20/2020
orangeg   5       11/20/2020
redg      5       11/20/2020

sheet2: 
name    fav    date
whiteg   1      4/29/2020
blackg   2      4/29/2020
grayg    3      4/29/2020
```

any suggestions?

Comment: The values in the dictionary are already DataFrames. You don't have to convert them. Do you want to combine them all into a single DataFrame?

Comment: No I wanted to change the view instead of looking at them in this format,  I wanted to see each one in a table format. is that possible?

Comment: `print(dict['Sheet1'])`?

Comment: that acutally helps. I actually have one more question if you wouldn't mind. Do you know How would loop through each dataframe in the dict and actually change a value in each one?

Comment: Please edit your question to focus it on this problem (i.e., trying to update one value in each of the dataframes in the dict) and provide a clear example of what element you are trying to update and what you expect as the result and someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over the items in a dictionary, use `.items()` and Python returns them as key, value pairs. In the dictionary returned by `read_excel()`, the key is the sheet name and the value is the dataframe. To access the dataframe, split the tuple into in the `for` statement and then manipulate the dataframe in-place:

```
dict = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name= None)

for sheet_name, df in dict.items():
   df['name'] = df['name'] + 'g'
```

Note: Using `dict` for the name of your dictionary shadows the built-in `dict()` function for creating dictionaries. You should use a different name.

Comment: In this example where you have 'name, df' did you switch my previous dict variable to df?

Comment: No, I didn't. I see how that could be confusing and I've updated my answer. Inside the `for` loop, `sheet_name` will contain the name of the sheet and `df` will be the dataframe for that sheet. I didn't change the dictionary name at all, it's still `dict`, but recommend that you change it in your code.

Comment: That works perfectly and thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

try the following to concatenate your dataframes:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
```

If you want to keep frames separated and simply perform an action, writing a loop should work, continued by a apply:

```
for _frame_name, _frame in dict:
    _frame["name"] = _frame["name"].apply(lambda x: x + "g", axis=0)
```

Comment: The only thing is I want to keep the sheets separate and just update certain columns/values simultaneously